# How can I center an entire DIV tag

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a problem that I can't figure it out. I just started learning HTML, CSS, JS and BOOTSTRAP.

My question is how can I center an entire DIV to the middle of the page? I mean all rows to be in the middle. This is what I have so far, and below the code you will see how I'd like it to be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSpbJ.jpg

```html
<div style="text-align: center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  <h4>
    Lasa-te inspirata de artistii nostri hair stylisti care iti vor crea un look ce iti va pune in valoare frumusetea naturala a parului tau, iti va accentua trasaturile si va evolua odata cu tine!
  </h4>

  <p>
    Stilistii salonului nostru de infrumusetare isi vor folosi cunostintele si experienta in hair styling pentru a crea un stil doar al tau. Asta este ceea ce ne defineste: personalizarea fiecarui serviciu de beauty pe care ti-l oferim, dupa o prealabila
    consultatie si diagnoza. De aceea te rugam sa iti acorzi cele 15 minute dedicate consultatiei YO, chiar si in cazul serviciilor expres, pentru ca noi sa putem afla cu exactitate care sunt dorintele tale si pentru a putea realiza in mod corect diagnoza
    firului de par astfel ca tu sa beneficiezi de tratamentele care ti se potrivesc. Am creat mediul cel mai bun astfel ca tu sa poti dezvolta o relatie pe termen lung cu coaforul tau preferat si de aceea te incurajam sa ne dai de stire atunci cand unul
    dintre produsele recomandate pentru a fi consumate acasa nu crezi ca ti se potriveste, politica noastra fiind : 100% satisfactie sau banii inapoi, pe loc!
  </p>
</div>
```

This is my code so far, but I want it to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a wrapper div element and set it to full width. Then make the inner div smaller, ex. 75% of its parent width and the `margin: auto` will do the trick for you (it adds auto margin on both sides, making your inner div centered),

```html
<div style="width: 100%; background-color: lightblue">
  <div style="text-align: left; width: 75%; margin: auto">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    <h4>
      Lasa-te inspirata de artistii nostri hair stylisti care iti vor crea un look ce iti va pune in valoare frumusetea naturala a parului tau, iti va accentua trasaturile si va evolua odata cu tine!
    </h4>

    <p>
      Stilistii salonului nostru de infrumusetare isi vor folosi cunostintele si experienta in hair styling pentru a crea un stil doar al tau. Asta este ceea ce ne defineste: personalizarea fiecarui serviciu de beauty pe care ti-l oferim, dupa o prealabila
      consultatie si diagnoza. De aceea te rugam sa iti acorzi cele 15 minute dedicate consultatiei YO, chiar si in cazul serviciilor expres, pentru ca noi sa putem afla cu exactitate care sunt dorintele tale si pentru a putea realiza in mod corect diagnoza
      firului de par astfel ca tu sa beneficiezi de tratamentele care ti se potrivesc. Am creat mediul cel mai bun astfel ca tu sa poti dezvolta o relatie pe termen lung cu coaforul tau preferat si de aceea te incurajam sa ne dai de stire atunci cand
      unul dintre produsele recomandate pentru a fi consumate acasa nu crezi ca ti se potriveste, politica noastra fiind : 100% satisfactie sau banii inapoi, pe loc!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you put a class on the div and in the style you put it to align it in the center.

```css
.test-center {
  align-content: center;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-center">
<span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
      <h4>
        Lasa-te inspirata de artistii nostri hair stylisti care iti vor crea un
        look ce iti va pune in valoare frumusetea naturala a parului tau, iti va
        accentua trasaturile si va evolua odata cu tine!
      </h4>

<div>
```

I hope it helps you, greetings!!

Answer (score 0):

To center horizontally, use `margin: auto`

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #eee;
}

#dot {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="dot"></div>
</div>
```

To center virtually, use `align-items`.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#dot {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="dot"></div>
</div>
```

Both ways

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-directon: column;
}

#dot {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="dot"></div>
</div>
```